# Generate reports from CosmosDB using Data warehouse

Tags: reporting-services, azure-sql-database, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, azure-synapse

I am using COSMOSDB for my application with SQL API.I need to generate the tabular and visualization reports from Azure COSMOSDB. What is the standard approach or any guidelines I need to refer.I guess directly connecting it with tool like Power BI or SSRS leads to certain hiccups. I need to analyse the data and accordingly generate the reports.Creating Data Warehouse is the best approach to generate such kind of reports but how to transfer data from NoSQL COSMOSDB to Azure SQL Datawarehouse.

Can anyone help me to clarify my doubts.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Power BI works fine on Cosmos DB.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/powerbi-visualize

That said, Cosmos DB is not an analytics data store. It is designed for operational workloads. Customers looking to do analytics on top of data in Cosmos typically do one of the following.

Use Change Feed to build "materalized views" of aggregates, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed or use Change Feed to write data into some other cold store for analytics including Spark.

Use Spark for analytics, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/spark-connector which can also include using Change Feed depending on whether you are looking to do Spark streaming.

Update: Building analytics on top of Cosmos DB today is most easily done using Synapse Link and either SQL or Spark for queryies, then connect Power BI to that for visualization.

Comment: I have no knowledge about spark but I need to know that can we create datawarehouse from nosql to sql?I got one reference link which has detail https://medium.com/@rkakodker/extracting-data-from-azure-cosmos-db-through-data-flow-pipelines-9bfc84fbd261. Is there any other approach?

Comment: Yes, using ADF is another approach. This Spring you'll be able to use Azure Synapse on top of Cosmos Analytical storage this will eliminate the need to build pipelines.